# Lightning problem with component.find("").getElements()

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, locker-service

I have a component

> ```
> <div class="tooltip" onmouseover="{!c.hover}">
>     <div >
>             <div >
>                Test Test Test
>             </div>
>     </div>
>     <div aura:id="textId" class="tooltiptext">
>         <div>Test Code</div>
>     </div>
> </div> </aura:component>
> ```

Css applied is

```
.THIS.tooltip { 
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block; 
}  

.THIS .tooltiptext { 
    visibility: hidden; 
    position: absolute; 
    word-wrap:break-word; 
    text-align: justify; 
}  

.THIS.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible; 
}
```

now in controller i want to use

> hover :(component){ component.find("textId").getElements(); }

error i am getting is

> [component.find(...).getElements is not a function]

this error occurs if **locker service is enabled**.

Is there any way to use component.find("").getElements() on div which is hidden?

Comment: Hi @ManjotSingh, Can you please post the complete code so that folks here can easily try it out and help you where you're stuck? As in which is the div with class name `textId` , `tooltiptext` ? Can you please make your question bit more clearer?

Comment: @SE_User Thnx for suggestion. I have made changes to code.

Comment: @ManjotSingh when you are saying "unable to getElements", are you getting an error or what is the behaviour you are seeing? If you could attach a screenshot of log it would help.

Comment: I am getting error [component.find(...).getElements is not a function]

Comment: @ManjotSingh i tried your code it works fine with one correction : `hover :function(component){ var divs = component.find("textId").getElements(); console.log(divs)}`

Comment: @Praveen is locker service enabled on your org? because this problem occurs if locker service is enabled on your org.

Comment: @ManjotSingh Locker is enabled in my org.

Comment: actually i tested my code by disabling locker service. it is working fine. but on enabling locker service it is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done some POC on this component and found out that i was using component.find("") on textId div on init of component. then afterwards whenever i was trying to use component.find(“textId”).getElements() on that div it was giving error because component.find(“textId”) was returning secure component reference. i changed my init method and added my logic onmouseover event now i am able to use component.find(“”).getElements().

Answer (score 3):

I've copied your exact same code and everything is working fine with LockerService on. I see 2 potential issues here.

1) You have multiple elements with `aura:id="textId"` in your markup. This would cause `component.find("textId")` to return an array of components and calling `getElements()` on the array will give you the error you report.

2) If it really is only happening with LockerService activated, your call to `component.find()` is likely returning a `SecureComponentRef` which doesn't have `getElements` defined on it, rather than a `SecureComponent` which does. This typically means you're trying to get a reference to a component that isn't in your current namespace. Are all components and the controller that makes the `getElements()` call in your namespace?

Comment: Thnx @Trevor But my problem was different. you can look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write your javascript code in the css - you need to to that in the component's controller.

From there you can code your component.find("textId") and handle your css values.

Comment: Actually my question is whether we can use component.find(“”).getElements() to div which is currently hidden. I can add slds-hide/slds-show class to my Div. But problem is when i add slds-hide to my div then try use getElements method it is not working.

Comment: the div exist so ofcourse you can - check within the page source elements if it exist

Comment: yes div exist in page source elements. But Problem is as Div is hidden then component.find(“”).getElements() doesnot work. if i change css to visibilty :visible then i am able to use component.find(“”).getElements().

Comment: Ok, I think you should refine your question then